# inhouse distribution of iphone development

Tags: iphone, testing, distribution

Can you anybody please about inhouse distribution of iphone development

Regards,
sathish

Comment: far better and more detailed (not to mention official) information can be found @ developer.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

What you need to look into is iPhone app [adhoc distribution](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/distribute.html).

Comment: Not if you have 100 employees or more.

Answer (score 1):

There are three kinds of distribution:

1. *Ad hoc*. You add the unique ID of up to 100 devices in the iPhone Provisioning Portal. You can then email your users the built app with the certificate that you generate with those IDs. This is usually used for beta testing.
2. App Store. You already know this and it's not what you want.
3. [Enterprise](https://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise.html). "Developers at companies with 500 or more employees who are creating proprietary in-house applications for iPad, iPhone or iPod touch should apply to the iPhone Developer Enterprise Program."

From your question I'm not sure whether you mean option 1 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

For enrollment in the Enterprise program you need '500 or more employees and a DUNS number' and $299 ([see here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/iphone/enterprise/)).

If you don't meet all of these criteria, you're basically stuck with ad hoc distribution. You can distribute to a maximum of 100 devices per paid Apple Developer Program account.